# Error in Keras Fitting

Tags: neural-network, keras

I am having the problem with the following python code which uses the library keras, and I have not been able to find a solution online:

```
       def model_build():
        model_mag=Sequential()
        model_mag.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=5))  
        model_mag.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model_mag.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
        model_mag.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model_mag.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
        model_mag.add(Dense(1))
        model_mag.compile(loss=losses.mean_squared_error,optimizer='sgd')
        return model_mag
       clf = KerasRegressor(build_fn=model_build(),nb_epoch=100)
       # here is the error
       clf.fit(X_train,y_train, nb_epoch=20)
```

I know that X_train and y_train are well defined above and I can run other classifier methods just fine with them so they are not the problem. It keeps throwing me the following error in the fit line and I can't figure out why:

TypeError: **call**() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

I am giving two arguments though.

Comment: Try this : `clf = KerasRegressor(build_fn=model_build,nb_epoch=100)`

Answer (score 1):

You have put `nb_epoch` in `fit`.

You have to remove `nb_epoch` from `fit`, and let it only in `KerasRegressor`.

Comment: I took away that part and tried just running clf.fit(X_train,y_train) and still have the same problem, any ideas?